# ¿Por qué no se muestra mi imagen en la base de datos? PHP - SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas estoy intentando crear un sistema para subir imágenes a mi web con PHP y SQL, logre que funcionase el sistema de destino (que la imagen se almacene en una carpeta del servidor) pero tengo un error y es que no se muestra la información de la imagen en la base de datos.

[image: IMAGEN]

**CODIGO: create.php**

```
<form method="post" action="./guardar_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Titulo</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Titulo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Descripcion</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Descripcion"></textarea>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">PORTADA</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image"></select>
    </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
        </form>
```

**CODIGO: guardar_post.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    include "connection.php";
    $con  = connect();
    var_dump($_POST["image"]);
    $sql = "insert into post (title,description,image,created_at) value (\"".$_POST["title"]."\",\"".$_POST["description"]."\",\"".$_POST["image"]."\",NOW())";
    
        if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
    }
    $con->query($sql);
    $last_id = $con->insert_id;
    $categorias = get_categorias();


    foreach($categorias as $cat){
        if(isset($_POST["category_".$cat->id])){
            var_dump($_POST["image"]);
        $sql = "insert into post_category (post_id,category_id,image) value (".$last_id.",".$cat->id.",".$_POST["image"].")";
        $con->query($sql);
        }
    }
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Actualmente la imagen si se almacena correctamente en el servidor pero no se muestra en la base de datos.

[image: IMAGEN 2]

Comment: ve tu consulta mySQL, estás guardando el post_id y el category_id, no el nombre de la imagen.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo | Edite la pregunta y lo agregue pero me esta dando el mismo error.

Comment: en BD no puedes guardar la imagen como tal, normalmente, si quieres guardar la imagen dentro de un SGBD, tendrías que convertir la imagen a base64, o, guardar el nombre del archivo en BD y lo referencias para accesar a ella.

Comment: ¿Ya has depurado lo que te devuelve la variable `$_POST["image"]`?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo | Disculpa y como podría hacer eso?

Comment: @MauricioContreras | A que te refieres?

Comment: @BetaM | En que parte del código debo agregar eso?

Comment: @BetaM Oh vale, ya lo agregue y ejecute el insert nuevamente. ¿Ahora que debo hacer? donde puedo verificar lo que trae

Comment: @BetaM | No me muestra nada, edite la pregunta para que puedas observar como lo agregue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es que en el momento de la construcción de la query que hace el insert usas $_POST['image'] y en este momento esa variable no existe. Puedes simplemente remplazar $_POST['image'] por $_FILES['image']['name'].

Esto será suficiente para guardar el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos, que supongo que es lo que quieres.

He modificado tu código para hacerte un par de recomendaciones. Debes agregar una columna "mime_type" a la tabla post que servirá luego para saber como mostrar/manipular la imagen

```
<?php

// incluye las dependencias en el nivel superior, asi es mas claro
include "connection.php";

// tu objeto $con probablemente ofrezca una función para el escapado de valores.
// Esta servirá, aunque lo mas recomendable es que uses la de la librería. Ya que
// la forma de escapar valores cambia según el sistema de base de datos usado.
function escape_value_for_query ($value) {
    return str_replace("'", "\\'", $value);
}

if (!isset($errors)) $errors = [];

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $con  = connect();
    
    // verificamos que el archivo se ha subido correctamente
    if (!$_FILES['image']['error']) {
        // crea variables locales, esto te ayuda a escribir código mas claro
        // ademas puedes aplicar algún tipo de validación antes de ejecutar la
        // lógica principal
        $title       = $_POST["title"];
        $description = $_POST["description"];
        $image       = $_FILES["image"];
        
        // Usa formato en tus consultas, serán mas fáciles de leer y modificar.
        // Aquí también hay un problema de seguridad estas poniendo las variables
        // directamente en el sql sin hacer un "escape" (o sea, limpiarlos) de los
        // valores, podrías ser víctima de sql injection.
        //
        // Entonces, aquí haremos algunos cambios:
        // 1. usar comillas simples para los valores
        // 2. escapar los valores. Sera suficiente con escapar las comillas simples
        $sql = "
            insert into post (
              title,
              description,
              mime_type, -- esta es una nueva columna en la base de datos para guardar el tipo mime de la imagen
              created_at
            ) values (
                '". escape_value_for_query($title) ."',
                '". escape_value_for_query($description) ."',
                '". escape_value_for_query($image['type']) ."',
                NOW()
            )
        ";
        
        // la recomendación aquí es que uses el id de la imagen como nombre final
        // asi no necesitas guardar el nombre de la imagen en la consulta anterior
        // ni hacer transformaciones del tipo id => name/name => id
        $con->query($sql);
        $imageId = $con->insert_id;
        
        $destination = "../images/" . $imageId;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        // una vez hemos verificado que no ha habido errores
        // esto solo puede fallar si:
        // 1. no hay espacio suficiente en disco para guardar la imagen
        // 2. no tenemos permisos para escribir en la carpeta destino
        if (!$result){
            array_push($errors, "¡Permisos insuficientes para escribir en el directorio de imágenes!");
        }
        
        $categorias = get_categorias();
        
        foreach($categorias as $cat){
            if(isset($_POST["category_".$cat->id])){
                // nuevamente aplicamos formato a la query
                // y aplicamos escapado:
                // 1. enteros con intval
                // 2. textos con escape_value_for_query
                $sql = "
                    insert into post_category (
                        post_id,
                        category_id
                    ) values (
                        " . intval($imageId) . ",
                        " . intval($cat->id) . "
                    )
                ";
                $con->query($sql);
            }
        }
    }
    
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit; // siempre aplica un exit luego de una redirección asi evitas que se ejecute el código siguiente
}

// elimina siempre el tag de cierre de php. usalo solo si vas a agregar html al archivo
```

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, pero ahora me guarda la imagen en el servidor con un nombre diferente de la base de datos. Por ejemplo | Servidor: 1606949788_helado | base de datos: helado.jpg | ¿Por qué ocurre eso?

Comment: Voy a editar mi respuesta para hacerte un par de recomendaciones en el mismo código

Comment: Gracias!, de verdad me ayudastes mucho, y discúlpame pero es que soy nuevo en php y base de datos pero porque ocurre eso que cambia el nombre de la imagen?

Comment: Ocurre porque el nombre que se usa en la base de datos es el que viene en la request. El que usas para guardar el archivo tiene el prefijo time(). He modificado tu código, haciendo un par se recomendaciones, déjame saber si necesitas algo más

Comment: Aplique los cambios y ahora las imágenes no se almacenan correctamente en mi servidor y tampoco en la base de datos

Comment: tienes algún error visible?

Comment: no, ahora en la carpeta de imágenes se guarda el archivo como "111.file" y en la base de datos no se muestra nada en la fila de "image"

Comment: y el foreach de las categorías dejo de funcionar también

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116898/discussion-between-jorge-miguel-sanchez-and-victor-hugo).

Answer (score 1):

Pues bien la respuesta más rápida es la siguiente.

primero pues fijar el nombre del archivo
y después fijar la ruta

```
<?php
  $imagen = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; //declaramos la variable que almacena el nombre del archivo
  $destino = './imagenes/'. $imagen; // y le decimos donde se va a guardar
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destino);//y aquí lo estamos pegando en la carpeta
    //posteriormente realizas lo que tengas que hacer y el nombre de tu archivo será
    $imagen // <--- Lo declaré arriba, esta es la variable que necesitas incorporar en tu sentencia de SQL de insert
  }
?>
```

Espero que te sirva de algo a estas alturas

Edit: el tmp_name que se observa, es requerido y no se puede modificar, pues es el nombre que estará cargando tu archivo.
Si, le puedes cambiar el nombre al archivo como tal declarando una variable que guarde los noombres

```
<?php
      $imagen = "El nombre que quieras .jpg/.png/etc"; 
      $destino = './imagenes/'. $imagen; 
      if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destino);
        $imagen // <--- Lo declaré arriba, esta es la variable que necesitas incorporar en tu sentencia de SQL de insert
      }
    ?>
```